# SQL to DynamoDb

Tags: sql, amazon-dynamodb

Our organization is planning to move MYSQL to Amazon dynamodb for data storage. Since using dyanmodb, I would like to know what is best approach for data transfer and we have to do some data manipulation before moving to dynamodb. Currently we have 1M records and I want to do it using .Net since I am a .Net developer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct data transfer tool or script that does the migration automatically. Actually, you need model your data before actual data transfer.

There are many good best practices for your consideration, e.g. [this one](http://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/migration-best-practices-rdbms-to-dynamodb.pdf).

By the way, .NET is perfect to use with DynamoDB.